# Has there been a change in policy relating to Duplicate Closures?

Tags: support, duplicates

I just happened to read the instructions for Duplicate Closure today. It says:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

See the image to be convinced:

[image: duplicate closure]

It asks the user to **ask a new question**. So far we used to ask the users to edit the question and flag for moderators/post on meta to get it reopened.

Has there been a change in policy?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166514/does-the-change-in-exact-duplicate-wording-imply-a-shift-in-policy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easier to ask a new, different question, than it is to edit a question and have it reopened, which is probably why Stack Exchange has amended this message. Just for future references, this is a system message that no one on the site outside of Stack Exchange has access to edit. If you consider "bigger" sites like Stack Overflow, who deal with hundreds of flags an *hour*. Having users edit a post and flag to be reopended would simply burden an already overtaxed queue. Here however, we can typically manage with those off chance cases that a question was too broad or interpreted. So continue to give what advice you see fit, there really hasn't been a policy either way though.